# Order array and group by occurrences

Tags: javascript, arrays

On input of

```
 array = [ 1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20 ]
```

and the output would be like

```
 [ [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2, 2 ], 4, 5, 10, [ 20, 20 ], 391, 392, 591 ]
```

Tried the following function to create the result:

```js
var array = [ 1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20]

function answer(ArrayFromAbove) {
  var length = array.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < (length - i - 1); j++) {
      if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
        var tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[j + 1];
        array[j + 1] = tmp;

      }
    }
  }
}
answer(array);
console.log(array);
```

Should return:

> [ [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ], [ 2, 2, 2 ], 4, 5, 10, [ 20, 20 ], 391, 392, 591 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove duplicates using `Set` and **`Array.prototype.sort()`** it. The get the count of number in array and `fill()` new `Array` and `push()` it to output.

```js
const array=[1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20]
function count(arr,num){
  return Array(arr.filter(x => x === num).length).fill(num);
}
const unique = [...new Set(array)].sort((a,b) => a -b);
const output = unique.map(un => {
  let arr = count(array,un);
  return (arr.length > 1) ? arr : un;
})
console.log(output)
```

The upper method is looping through array my times. You can do by looping two times by following method

```js
let array=[1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20]
array = array.sort((a,b) => a-b);
const result = [];
let temp = [];
for(let i = 0;i<array.length + 1;++i){
  if(array[i - 1] === array[i] || i === 0){
    temp.push(array[i]);
  }
  else{
    result.push((temp.length === 1) ? temp[0] : temp);
    temp = [array[i]];
  }
}
//result.push(temp)
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what is sort in the code mean?Sorry,my teacher doesn't teach me sort

Comment: @Jacky it sorts the array.

Comment: so it sorts the array into an ordered list?

Comment: @Jacky in this case its sorting array in **ascending order** but you can have give it any logic. See in my answer i have added a **link**

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using `reduce` instead, counting up the occurences of each number, then iterating over the sorted entries and pushing the value to the result array (as an array, if there are multiple values, or as just a plain number, if there's only one):

```js
const input = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20];
/* create an object like:
{
  "1": 4,
  "2": 3,
  "4": 1,
  "5": 1,
  "10": 1,
  "20": 2,
  "391": 1,
  "392": 1,
  "591": 1
} */
const inputCounts = input.reduce((a, num) => {
  a[num] = (a[num] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});

const output = Object.entries(inputCounts)
  // turn (string) key to number:
  .map(([key, val]) => [Number(key), val])
  .sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
  .reduce((a, [num, count]) => {
    a.push(
      count === 1
      ? num
      : new Array(count).fill(num)
    );
    return a;
  }, []);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count the occurences, then create arrays based on the counts:

```
 const counts = new Map;

 for(const value of array.sort())
   counts.set(value, (counts.get(value) || 0) + 1);

const result = [];

for(const [count, value] of counts.entries())
  result.push(new Array(count).fill(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

- Sort the array using [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to create the resulting array

  - For the first value, simply add the value to resulting array
  - For next all values, check whether the last value in resulting array is an array
  - If the last value is an array, match the first value in array with current value.

    - If the value is same, push it to the last value array
    - Else push it to the main resulting array
  - Else match the last value with current value

    - If the value is same, replace the entry in resulting array with an array containing 2 values
    - Else push it to the main resulting array

```js
let array = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20];
let result = array.sort((a,b) => a-b).reduce((a,c) => {
  if(a.length) {
    let lastVal = a[a.length-1];
    if(Array.isArray(lastVal)) {
      if(lastVal[0] == c) lastVal.push(c);
      else a.push(c);
    } else if(lastVal == c) a[a.length-1] = [c,c];
    else a.push(c);
  }
  else a.push(c);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce and than fill the array as per the number of occurrences   of number

```js
var array = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20]

let reduced = array.reduce((op,inp)=>((op[inp] ? op[inp]++ : (op[inp]=1)),op),{})

let op = Object.keys(reduced).map(e=>(reduced[e] === 1 ? e : new Array(reduced[e]).fill(e)))
        .sort((a,b)=> (Array.isArray(a) ? a[0] : a) - (Array.isArray(b) ? b[0] : b) )

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array, group all number into an sub-array, then replace those array with only one element to the element.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20]
function answer(arr){
 arr.sort((a,b) => a - b);
 var tempResult = [];
 while(arr.length > 0){
  var val = arr.shift();
  if(tempResult.length == 0 || tempResult[tempResult.length-1][0] !== val){
   tempResult.push([val]);
        }else{
   tempResult[tempResult.length-1].push(val);
        }
    }
 
 while(tempResult.length > 0){
  var subArr = tempResult.shift();
  if(subArr.length == 1) arr.push(subArr[0]);
  else arr.push(subArr);
    }
 
}
answer(array);
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.reduce()` & `Array.sort()` to accumulate the duplicates into an object, then filtering and the mapping the elements into a new array based on the key of the duplicate objects.

```js
const array=[1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20].sort((a,b)=> a - b);

let acc = array.reduce((acc, ele, idx, arr) => {
   if(ele === arr[idx+1] && acc[ele]){
     acc[ele] = acc[ele].concat(ele) ;
   }else if(ele === arr[idx+1]){
    acc[ele] = [ele].concat(ele);
   }
   return acc;
}, {});
let result = array.filter((ele, idx, arr) => ele !== arr[idx+1]).map((ele) => acc[ele]? acc[ele]: ele);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20]

function answer (input) {
  return input.sort((a,b) => a - b)
    .reduce((collect, next) => {
      // First item, just add it
      if (!collect.length) {
        collect.push(next)
        return collect
      }
      let prev = collect.pop()
      if (Array.isArray(prev)) {
        let [ num ] = prev
        if (num === next) {
          prev.push(next)
          collect.push(prev)
          return collect
        } else {
          collect.push(prev, next)
          return collect
        }
      } else if ( prev === next ) {
        collect.push([prev, next])
        return collect
      } else {
        collect.push(prev, next)
        return collect
      }
    }, []);
}

console.log(answer(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [1, 2, 4, 591, 392, 391, 2, 5, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 20, 20]
var resultArray = []
var subArray = []
var length = array.length;
array.sort(function sortArray(a,b) {
    return a - b;
});
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if(subArray.length == 0 || subArray[0] == array[i])
    {
        subArray.push(array[i]);
    }
    else if(subArray.length > 1 && array[i] != subArray[0])
    {
        resultArray.push(subArray);
        subArray = [array[i]];     
    }
    else if(subArray.length == 1 && array[i] != subArray[0])
    {
        resultArray.push(subArray[0]);
        subArray = [array[i]];
    } 
}
if(subArray.length == 1)
{
    resultArray.push(subArray[0]);
}
else
{
    resultArray.push(subArray);
}
console.log(resultArray);
//return(resultArray);
```